# Instagram Webhook for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

The documentation for webhook is in javascript and i am looking for rails code.

```
app.post('/instagram', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Instagram request body:');
  console.log(req.body);
  // Process the Instagram updates here
  received_updates.unshift(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

'req.body', How do i type that in the rails controller?

Here is the link to the entire sample project for webhook.
https://github.com/fbsamples/graph-api-webhooks-samples/blob/master/heroku/index.js

I am trying to get the comments in Instagram Media posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

```
require 'rest-client'

response = RestClient.post('/instagram')
response.body
```

[Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)

```
require 'net/http'

response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI('/instagram'))
response.body
```